# How to mask the users input in a Batch file

Tags: batch-file, passwords, password-protection

Im a beginner and i have a question about how i can mask the users input.

this is my code:

```
:Password  
echo Password:  
set /p pw=   
if %pw% EQU valarmorgulis goto Main  
if not %pw% EQU valarmorgulis goto Password  
pause > nul
```

I want the inputs that the user types in to not be shown on screen.

can anyone help me with that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This doesn't look to be something trivial ... but there are many other questions on here that answer your question: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/668455/6577822), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/665191/6577822), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36292638/6577822)

Comment: @LotPings Whoops my mistake. Sorry for my non-sense. Here's a snippet from ss64: `EQU will perform a numeric comparison where possible, if you need a string comparison use the == comparison operator.` I should said that instead.

Comment: I already looked into these topics, but i couldnt get any of the solutions posted there to work. As i said, im a beginner and dont know much about batch. Any easy solution for my problem?

Comment: @LotPings I'm not sure how `cmd` processes `EQU` and `==`, I'm also not sure if ss64's information is misleading. But I agree with what you said.

Comment: @DannyD How about some external tools?

Comment: @SteveFest I didnt try any external tools.

Answer (score 0):

Herbert Kleebauer wrote several tools for hidden input.
An [early one](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3721) only usable in 16/32bit environment with .com files.

[This latter version](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/alt.msdos.batch.nt/8iJ2CrmtStk/Vx46E8xXDCcJ) uses certutil to decode the base64 encoded .exe file.

To be able to verify integrity source code is included.