# Password masking with a batch file

Tags: batch-file, passwords, masking

In the current scenario, when I run the batch file, the window prompt to enter the password.When I enter the password, characters are visible in the window prompt.
I want to mask password.

As of now, for entering password, I have below code in my batch file.

```
SET /p v_password=Enter user password:
```

what code should I embed here to mask the password.

Answer (score 1):

To mask the password; You can use the powershell method like posted here in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36291324/batch-file-command-hide-password?answertab=active#tab-top)

---

```bat
@echo off
set "psCommand=powershell -C "$pword = read-host 'Enter Password' -AsSecureString ; ^
    $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set password=%%p
echo %password%
pause
```

---

Here is an example to show you how to use the powershell command into a batch file :

```bat
@echo off
Title %~n0
Mode 50,5 & Color 0E
:CreatePassword
cls & Color 0E
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
Call :InputPassword "Please choose your password" pass1
Call :InputPassword "Please confirm your password" pass2
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
If !pass1!==!pass2! ( Goto:Good ) Else ( Goto:Bad )
::***********************************
:InputPassword
Cls
echo(
set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host '%1' -AsSecureString ; ^
    $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
      [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
        for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set %2=%%p
Goto :eof
::***********************************        
:Good
Color 0B                  
Cls
echo.
echo                     Good password
::TimeOut /T 2 /NoBreak>nul
echo Your password stored as : "!Pass2!" without quotes
pause>nul
Goto :Eof
::***********************************
:Bad
Color 0C
Cls
echo.
echo             Wrong password try again
::TimeOut /T 2 /NoBreak>nul
echo  Press any key to retry again
pause>nul
Goto :CreatePassword
::***********************************
```

Comment: Can you please explain the above code.

Comment: With the first code I am able to mask the password in asterisk, but then not able to login.